# AngularJS Routing Issues

Tags: c#, javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I can't seem to get anything displayed in my div which has the attribute "ng-view".

Here is my controller;

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module("userViewer", []);

var MainController = function ($scope, $location) {
    console.log("Main controller");
    $scope.search = function () {

        console.log("User ID: " + $scope.userid);
        //Right Route Here
    };
};

app.controller("MainController", MainController);
}());
```

Here is my app.js:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module("userViewer", ['ngRoute']);
console.log("Test route");
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/main", {
            templateUrl: "html/main.html",
            controller: "MainController"

        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/main" });
});
}());
```

My master template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="userViewer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

My angular SPA main page html body:

```
<h2>Header</h2>

<div ng-view>

</div>
```

My main.html

```
<div>
    <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search()">
        <input type="search" required ng-model="userid" placeholder="User ID to find" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

My console.log within app.js "Test route prints but when I navigate to URL/#/main nothing is shown.

Just the word "Header" and the main.html view is not loaded atall.

There is also no errors displayed in the console.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Looks like you are defining twice "userViewer" module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you are doing this

```
var app = angular.module("userViewer", []);
```

When you put the [] in there you are creating a new module. Try

```
var app = angular.module("userViewer");
```

to reference your existing one.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module("userViewer", ['ngRoute']);
console.log("Test route");
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/main", {
            templateUrl: "/html/main.html", <-- try to locate the view starting from the root path of the app
            controller: "MainController"

        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/main" });
});
}());
```

try to define your controller as:

```
angular.module('userViewer').controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    //your code here
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

change app.js to

```
(function () {


    var MainController = function ($scope, $location) {
        console.log("Main controller");
        $scope.search = function () {

            console.log("User ID: " + $scope.userid);
            //Right Route Here
        };
    };

app.controller("MainController", MainController);
}());
```